# Connecting a domain with ssh

Tags: ssh

Yesterday, I was looking for different job advertisements and one of them got my attention. They are taking job applications through SSH.
their [advertisement](https://www.5monkeys.se/) was like `Apply by connecting to join.xyz.se via SSH and follow the instructions.`
This concept was entirely new to me and I want to know how can we connect them through ssh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a shell session and login, just like with telnet in the old days.  Below is an example.  join.xyz.se was not even resolvable for me just now, and I did not know the username/password for [www.sdf.org](http://www.sdf.org) (typically it would be anonymous/anonymous or made known to you somehow; the username is spec'd before the @ as shown below):

```
Mac_3.2.57$ssh anonymous@join.xyz.se
ssh: Could not resolve hostname join.xyz.se: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Mac_3.2.57$ping join.xyz.se
ping: cannot resolve join.xyz.se: Unknown host
Mac_3.2.57$ssh anonymous@www.sdf.org
anonymous@www.sdf.org's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```